# Faild To Match os.type() in a nodejs application using heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am creating an simple application where i want to show the main page only on windows based systems.if its windows then its shows the index page else it will show the error page. it works perfectly locally but when deployed it wont works. always shows the error page.

```
const platform = os.platform();
const type = os.type();


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
 if (type == "Windows_NT") {
     res.render('index');
 } else {
     res.render('error');
 }
});
```

Comment: It seems like your Heroku machine is not of type Windows_NT

Comment: then what can i do to solve this issue?